# Converting SQL statement to JPQL statement and use it

Tags: sql-server, jsp, jpa-2.1

I want to make report for top 10 most table ordered in time range : but i can not

- I have 2 entity class :

  1. DiningDable.java  (`SELECT d FROM Diningtable d`).
  2. Ordertabledetail.java  (`SELECT o FROM Ordertabledetail o`).

  In entity class 1 have information of table so i want to display. In entity class 2 have date of order.
- My "viewReport" Method in sesionBean

  ```
      public List viewReport(Date startDate, Date endDate) {
          try {
              Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT o.tableID.tableID AS tableID , COUNT(o.tableID.tableID) FROM Ordertabledetail o WHERE o.date BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate GROUP BY o.tableID.tableID ORDER BY o.tableID.tableID DESC").setParameter("startDate", startDate, TemporalType.DATE).setParameter("endDate", endDate, TemporalType.DATE);
              List<Ordertabledetail> result = query.getResultList();
              return result;
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
      }
  ```
- My servlet

  ```
      String action = request.getParameter("action_report");
      String url = "/admin/minh_report.jsp";   
      if (action.equals("View")) {
          SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

          String startDate = request.getParameter("txtDateFrom");
          String endDate = request.getParameter("txtDateTo");

          Date sdate = formatter.parse(startDate);    
          Date edate = formatter.parse(endDate);


          List list = orderTableDetailBean.viewReport(sdate, edate);
          request.setAttribute("UN", list);      
          url = "/admin/minh_report.jsp";
          request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
      }
  ```

How can I show the information of 10 most tables were ordered in a JSP page?

Comment: Can you describe what error you are getting and add the message to the question?

Comment: Please paste the entities (fields should be enough).